# Remove duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have an error when trying to update a table.
When I'm updating the table I get the error message:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.DimAdmin' with unique index 'Admin_UserID'. The duplicate
>   key value is (C2Botha).

When I look at the table properties using SQL Assist, I saw a lightning bolt icon next to the field I'm trying to update. What does this ightning bolt icon mean? Does it mean that the field cannot contain duplicate values.

Please advise

Comment: So you are trying to insert a row with a key which already exists in the table or updating the key of a row to a key which already exists. What do you want from us? We can't see your code, we can't see your data; there is not much to tell you.

Comment: is this for mysql or for sql-server ? they are both very different databases please choose one

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear that tells you there is already an record which `UserID` is `C2Botha`. There is a unique index on that column. So, you can't insert another one in same. There are two options here.

1. Delete the existing record and be careful with that. It might cause
   related data problems.
2. Or you can update the existing record.

Comment: if you setup foreign keys as you are supposed to and made sure that cascade delete is off (as its supposed to be) then deleting will never cause any related data problems. That is why we use relational database in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The Error message says the Column that you are trying to Update or Insert already has that value in any of the rows.

**Since you have created a UNIQUE index, you can't have duplicates for that column**.

So make sure that for the column, the value 'C2Botha' does not exist.

Check for existence before inserting the record. Or it is also possible that If your insert list has duplicates, then it will throw the same error and it won't be captured in the Existence check query in the table.

You can check the Existence in either of the following ways

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Yourtable WHERE <Condition>)
BEGIN
<Insert Query>
END
```

Or Like This

```
INSERT INTO YourTable1
SELECT
* 
FROM YourTable2 YT2 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM YourTable1 YT1 WHERE YT1.ID = YT2.ID
)
```

Comment: I'm not performing an insert operation. I just need to update the records where a match is found.The problem is in the table that I am trying to update the table I have two records that I need to update but the Admin_UserID is the same other than that the record is totally different from each other. And the Admin_UserID is not the primary key of the table. However it does have that lightning bolt next to it. Which I'm assuming that it means the column must be unique.

Comment: looking at your errormessage you posted it is impossible that you see 2 records with the same Admin_UserID. Your not telling us all ?